# Permanently storing a buffer value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse the lines of a text file and then store them inside of a `vector<string>`.    I'm coming from a Java background and am confused on how C++ handles assigning stuff to the value of a buffer.  Here is my code:

```
string line;
vector<string> adsList;
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("test.txt");
while(getline(inputFile, line))
{
    adsList.push_back(line);
}
```

In Java, when adding to a data structure a copy of the object is made and then that copy is inserted.  In C++, my understanding is that the data structures only hold references so that any operation is very fast.  What is the proper way to achieve what I want to do in C++?  I have also tried the following code:

```
vector<string> adsList;
string line;
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("test.txt");
while(getline(inputFile, line))
{
    string *temp = new string;
    *temp = line;
    adsList.push_back(*temp);
}
```

With my reasoning here being that creating a new string object and storing that would preserve it after being destroyed each loop iteration.  C++ seems to handle this completely opposite of Java and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

edit: here is what test.txt looks like:

```
item1 item1 item1
item2 item2 item2
item3 item3 item3
item4 item4 item4
```

I'm trying to store each line as a string and then store the string inside my vector.  So the front of the vector would have a string with value "item1 item1 item1".

Comment: What is ``inputFile``? You should declare it like this: ``ifstream inputFile;``, have you done that?

Comment: @hinafu sorry, I do it like that, but forgot to include that.  will edit.

Comment: well, the first code you put should work, maybe the file isn't in the same location the program is.

Comment: @hinafu The OP is asking about *copies* vs *references*. He isn't asking how to read a file.

Comment: ``What is the proper way to achieve what I want to do in C++?`` He's trying to do something, maybe he wasn't reading the file the right way.

Comment: I may not be reading the file correctly.  If I print everything out only the last value displays correctly.  I will try to implement some of the suggestions.

Comment: @trevor-e Post the code that you're using for displaying the results. Ie, **show all your code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push_back()` makes a copy, so your first code sample does exactly what you want it to do. In fact, all C++ structures store copies by default. You'd have to have a container of *pointers* to not get copies.

Comment: When I try to print out my vector everything but the last value is blank.  Any idea for the cause of that?

Comment: @trevor-e That would depend on what's in your file. Can you edit your question to show your entire code as well as the sample file you want to read?

Comment: Turns out my display library was not working correctly and my first code did work.  I will mark this correct because it is the most concise answer to my confusion though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post the entire code, I suggest you try this to see if it is reading the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  fstream inputFile("test.txt",fstream::in);
  string l;
  vector<string> v;
  while(getline(inputFile,l)) v.push_back(l);
  //Display the content of the vector:
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    cout << v[i] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out I was doing it correctly and the problem was with the display library I'm using (ncursew).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding re references is incorrect - Java stored references, C++ stores whatever you ask it to , be it `pointers` or `copies` (note you can't store references in stl containers, the equivalent is pointers)

`vector::push_back` stores a **copy** of the item being stored in the vector - so you don't have to create a `pointer`, and `new` some memory on the heap in order to store the string.

(Internally, there **is** some heap allocation going on, but that's implementation details of `std::string`)

What option we **do** have in C++ is to rather store `pointers`, and these you **have to** heap allocate, otherwise when the current stack frame is popped off, the pointers will be pointing to defunct memory... but that is another topic.

See here for a simple working example of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> adsList;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("test.txt");

    // read a line from the file - store it in 'line'
    while(getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        // store a *copy* of line in the vector
        adsList.push_back(line);
    }

    // for each element in adsList vector, get a *reference* (note the '&')
    for (std::string& s : adsList)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial assumption is incorrect. A copy is (generally) stored in `vector` (ignoring move operations which were brought in with C++11). Generally, this is the way you want to be operating.

If you are truly worried about speed and want to store references (pointers, actually) to things, you'll want to utilize something like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. For example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> adsList;
std::string line;
inputFile.open("test.txt");
while(std::getline(inputFile, line)) {
    adsList.push_back(std::unique_ptr<std::string>(new std::string(line));
}
```

Generally this is only done if you must be able to modify the values in the container and have the modifications reflected to the original object - in this case you'd use a `std::shared_ptr`. By far the most common scenario is your first code example.